# Как сделать такую кастомную страницу в админке

Tags: wordpress

Есть список квартир. Все данные будут браться только из произвольных полей (стоимость, район, кол-во комнат). Нужна страница в админке, где будет выводиться список этих квартир (если есть) и их можно будет добавлять, удалять. Если делать каждую квартиру через "Записи", то будет пустовать ненужное поле описания, да и просматривать неудобно. Как это лучше реализовать?

Нашёл только как создавать кастомную страницу в админке, но как туда поместить кастомные *поля*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как это лучше реализовать?

Создать [пользовательский тип контента](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_types#Custom_Post_Types) (типа post) с нужными полями (в тч и [произвольными](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F)) и нужными [пользовательскими таксономиями](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Сделал практически так, как надо. Осталось только изменить вид списка с недвижимостью.